# powershell script to exe with command line arguments

Tags: powershell, site-collection, script

I use the following PowerShell code taking command line arguments for creating site collections and it works fine.

However when I convert it into an exe and execute it?

```
param(
[string]$siteUrl,[string]$siteOwner,[string]$template,[string]$siteTitle,[int]$siteCount
)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")

Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
try
{

    Start-SPAssignment -Global

        if ($siteCount -eq 1)
        {
            New-SPSite ($siteUrl + "1") -OwnerAlias $siteOwner -Name $siteTitle -Template $template
        }
        else
            {
                for ($i=1; $i -le $siteCount; $i++)
                    {
                        New-SPSite ($siteUrl + $i) -OwnerAlias $siteOwner -Name ($siteTitle + "-" + $i) -Template $template
                    }
            }



    Stop-SPAssignment -Global
    Exit 0
}
catch 
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Output $ErrorMessage
    Exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet to create site collection

```
SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://WebApp"));
webApp.Sites.Add("/sites/site1", "Description", null, 1033, null, "administrator", "Administrator", "admin@contoso.com"))
```

You can read command line arguments using

```
if (args == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("args is null"); // Check for null array
}
else
{
    Console.Write("args length is ");
    Console.WriteLine(args.Length); // Write array length
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) // Loop through array
    {
        Console.Write(argument); // Write string

        //USE THIS argument for creating site collection
    }
}
```